# How to expand an object

Tags: extrude

I have an .stl file of a fan cover. I need to expand it, or stretch it, from the front and pull it out about three times it's depth. I've looked at Youtube videos on extruding and stretching but I can't get it to move in the right direction.

Thank you for any help.

Here is the .stl file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqkf2dkcinmrgax/hotend_fan_shroud_cover_remix.stl?dl=0

Comment: could you please show some pictures or a gif or a video of how you fail with this object?

Comment: I tried using Simple Deform to stretch the front of this fan cover out but the stretch doesn't stretch correctly. It should pull out in the Y axis but doesn't pull out the way I need it to pull. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8i4mac5moqtgplc/2020-09-22_085659.jpg?dl=0    https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qb7qo1ywgwvwk1/2020-09-22_085716.jpg?dl=0

Comment: so you want to move the face? In that case, go in Edit mode, select the whole face and move on the Y axis with G and Y?

Comment: I got into edit mode but cannot select the face as a whole. Only small parts of it select. Maybe this object I cannot do what I want to do. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga7594h3qmlhqdn/2020-09-22_113955.jpg?dl=0

Comment: switch to X ray mode (alt Z) then select with the lasso, then drag on the Y axis

Comment: Thank you for the help but I can't figure out how to do that. Blender is just too complicated. I've never used it before and I just wanted to do this one stretch on my .stl file. I'll have to figure out something else. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Edit mode (tab), choose the left view (3), and switch to X Ray (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) to be able to select through:

[image]

Choose the *Lasso Select* tool (or use the shortcut):

[image]

Select the part of your mesh you want, press shift to select again:

[image]

Switch to the Move tool (or shortcut <kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Move the selection, use the gizmo to move on the Y axis or press Y to contrain on this axis:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!